# Unity Сборка в .exe

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Можно ли собрать приложение в один файл?
Обычно есть папка с файлами, но есть ли способ все засунуть в один .exe файл?

Comment: ну так когда вы комплируете проект вы получаете exe-шник.

Comment: и помимо него несколько файлов в папке, а  мне интересно можно ли как то обойтись без этих доп. фалов

Comment: [Resources in .NET apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/resources). Засуньте файлы в ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот, используй этот упаковщик, или любую другую альтернативу:
https://jazzteam.org/ru/technical-articles/manual-creating-an-installer-using-inno-setup/

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на ресурс. Здесь не принято оставлять ответы-ссылки т.к. они могут стать неактивными через время. Необходимо что бы ответ был самодостаточным без перехода по ссылке